# Passive Bluetooth Beacons

Tags: rf, bluetooth-low-energy

I read a white paper earlier on that implied that Passive Beacons were on the horizon (which I will accept could mean 10 years away).

My head's spinning thinking about the applications of mixing active and passive beacons, and I have a lot of thoughts on what they might have actually meant, or what research could be going on, but I'm honestly not even remotely experienced enough in electronics or RF to be able to decide whether or not I should be excited.

In your experience/with your educated opinion, would you say this is actually a possibility?

EDIT/UPDATE:
My question is - Are Passive BLE Beacons a possibility for commercial users within the next 5-10 years?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, BT LE beacons have been on the market for some time. For example Apple developed the iBeacon in 2013 (it isn't widespread, but it is there) and has support in both iOS and Android 4.2+ devices. Passive devices would have the same applications but work more like RFID tags.

Comment: Your question seems to be *"would you say this is actually a possibility?"*, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what *this* actually is. Are you asking about the eventual existence of passive beacons? That's an opinion question, and off-topic here.

Comment: Yes you're both correct; yes that is my question. Sorry I didn't realise I was being so vague. I'm looking for input from someone who knows about modern BLE circuitry and could say whether they thought this technology was likely to become ubiquitous or at least commercially available within the next 5 years; "this" is Passive BLE receivers or transmitters. "Passive" being powerless as in passive-RFID (as opposed to active-RFID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a startup company ([Wiliot](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/telecom/wireless/startup-wiliot-promises-nobattery-bluetooth-beacons-in-2019)) that works on powerless beacon. According to their road-map, the powerless beacon will be available in the market and under 1$ price in 2019.

Comment: Excellent, I couldn't find anything and this is all I needed to hear! Thanks!